# change td table background by id click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table of few companies, and I have menu like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#a"><img src="a"  /></a></li>
<li><a href="#b"><img src="b"  /></a></li>
<li><a href="#c"><img src="c"  /></a></li>
</ul>
```

In my table, I have td's with the id's: a,b,c and I want to change the td's background for few seconds when the the id of td's same as the menu option

Comment: 1) What menu option? How is it set, and where do you get it's value? 2) please show the code you've written to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  Responding to a click event?  Identifying the element to change?  Changing the element's style?  You have to describe what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to use for this [:target pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
    0% {background: coral;}
    100% {background: inherit;}
}
@keyframes highlight {
    0% {background: coral;}
    100% {background: inherit;}
}

td:target {
    -webkit-animation: highlight 1s ease-out; 
    animation: highlight 1s ease-out; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#a"><img src="a"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#b"><img src="b"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#c"><img src="c"></a></li>
</ul>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="a">A</td>
        <td id="b">B</td>
        <td id="c">C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i'ts good! but it's change only one td with the id.. and it's working for only one click, when I clicking again, it's does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

heres a jquery solution (with also jquery ui)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).css('background', 'red').animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#a"><img src="a"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#b"><img src="b"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#c"><img src="c"></a></li>
</ul>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="a">A</td>
        <td id="b">B</td>
        <td id="c">C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```